# How to use maths to solve this daily life problem.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

*13* men take *20* days to complete a job working *9* hours a day. How many hour a day should *40* men work to complete the job?

So my approach is that I calculated how much time the *13* men worked that is:

```
9h·20days=180 in total
```

And I used this rule

```
180 h --------> 13 men

x   h --------> 40 men
```

And so

```
x=(180·40)/13=553.846153846
```

But I calculated only total hours of working, so I didn't determine the number of days or of hours a day, so this approach fails. Could somebody show me a better approach?

Comment: Shall the job still be completed in 20 days?

Comment: I should find both the days to complete a job and the working hours per day ::

Comment: If this is a "daily life problem" for you, you lead a very different life from mine.

Comment: Yeah I know mathematicians see the world differently than us normal people, I wish I was better at maths in school

Comment: You calculated the total number of hours(180 hrs) that one person worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing the wrong calculation.

The total number of man-hours required for the job is $9\times 20\times 13 = 2340$

If there are $40$ men they need to do $\frac {2340}{40}=58.5$ hours each in total. The number of hours per day depends on the number of days.

Reality check - the number of men increases by a factor of about $3$. So the number of hours per day should be about a third of what it was if the number of days stays the same. Or if the number of hours per day stays the same, the number of days is just less than a third of what it was.

Answer (score 0):

39 men equals 3x of 13 people working to complete the work.
180/3=60 hours.

39 men= 60 hours or 2 days 5 hours 
plus 1 man to equal 40
180/13=13.8

so 1 man= 13.8

60+13.8=73 hours and 8 min. or 3 days estimated for 40 men to complete the job..